# Allow Shell Script to Access Protected Library Folders (launchd)

Tags: macos, bash, permission, launchd

I'm trying a bash script that works fine when run from the command line (Terminal).

Apart from the shebang, it just has:

```
ls -alt /Users/<username>/Libary/Mail/V6/.../Lists.mbox
```

(Using `ls` as a simple command to illustrate the problem.)

However, when I try a test run using launchd (which I set up using the Lingon X app) I get a permissions error.

```
1: Operation not permitted
ls: Lists.mbox: Operation not permitted
```

Terminal and Lingon X both have Full Disk Access allowed in Privacy pref pane, but I don't see any way to allow an individual shell script to be given such access.

I've tried running the same script using AppleScript's `do shell script` but I get the same error.

The (.sh) script permissions are set to 755, so this should not be a factor.

How can I get around this please?

Comment: What user is the launchd script running as?

Comment: It makes no difference whether it's a user with admin privileges or as root. SIP still prevents access to ~/Library unless specific permission to have full disk access is granted.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for SIP protecting user files I thought it was just for common files e.g. /Library

Comment: I assumed Full Disk Access was part of SIP, but it may not be. This is what I found (on one app's site explaining why it needed to be granted such access): "Starting with macOS 10.14, Mojave; VirusBarrier and Personal Backup require Full Disk Access to scan your Mail, Messages, Safari files, and other user data." I'll edit my answer to remove 'SIP' but the rest is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame the issue by creating an application wrapper for the script using Platypus - https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus.

I gave the resultant app Full Disk Access in the Privacy pref pane and this allowed it to run.

(Any subsequent change to the core script means regenerating the app and removing and re-adding it in Privacy as the new file is not recognised as having Full Disk Access.)