# How do I delete files on user login?

Tags: command-line, login, macos, customization

I'm trying to set up a custom user that deletes files and folders in the home directories (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Movies and Pictures) when a user logs in/logs out, similar to how the guest user works. I'm able to get a script that locks the dock to work at log-in but for some reason my script to delete all files and directories in these folders doesn't work. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /users/student/desktop/*
rm -rf /users/student/documents/* 
rm -rf /users/student/downloads/* 
rm -rf /users/student/pictures/* 
rm -rf /users/student/music/* 
rm -rf /users/student/movies/* 
defaults write com.apple.Dock size-immutable -bool yes
defaults write com.apple.Dock contents-immutable -bool yes; killall Dock
```

The last two lines run perfectly when logging in, but my `rm -rf` lines don't. To confirm, my problem isn't getting the script to run at login - I have a `LaunchAgent` that works, it's **getting the `rm -rf` command to work at login**, or using an alternative that does the job. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the `LaunchAgent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.local.cleanUser</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/cleanUser.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You could try running `rm -r /Users/student/Desktop/* >> /Users/student.log 2>&1` within the script once to see any errors.

Comment: This is what is returned:

`line 5: /Users/student.log: Permission denied`

Comment: So the script isn't running as user `student`?

Comment: The script is in usr/local/bin, because the files i want to delete are in `student` is this the right place for the script to be? If anything, I thought this would be overkill for permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a sudo command at login/logout on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423278/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-at-login-logout-on-macos)

Comment: This was my original question I posted yesterday which helped me run the script at login, but now I'm having trouble with some of the code working then @Ant

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is stored, it matters who is the owner of the LaunchAgent (or the user specified in there)

Comment: @nohillside I have used `chmod u+x` on both `.plist` and `.sh` files, still no luck.

Comment: @nohillside tried `chmod u+x` on the directories I want to delete, didn't work.

Comment: If it works if run manually the issue is not with the directories. Can you add the LaunchAgent plist to the question?

Comment: And use `rm -r /Users/student/Desktop/* >> /tmp/student.log 2>&1` for logging, any user should have write access to `/tmp`

Comment: @nohillside Updated the question with the LaunchAgent and will try again now with the log file going to /tmp

Comment: @nohillside student.log returns this: `rm: /Users/student/Desktop/*: No such file or directory`

Comment: We probably end up with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367020/allow-shell-script-to-access-protected-library-folders-launchd?rq=1

Comment: This won't stop the script from working though, there are just no files to delete on the desktop. Did you add the output option to all rm commands? and what does `ls -l /tmp/student.log` return?

Comment: Removed the other `rm` commands for now just to get it working on the Desktop. and `ls -l /tmp/student.log` returns `-rw-r--r--@ 1 student  wheel  168 30 Jun 10:53 /tmp/student.log`

Comment: Ok. Then create a file on the desktop and try again, should work. If it does, add the otheer commands (and make sure there are files to delete). I would assume that deleting from Documents will fail.

Comment: @nohillside Same thing, log saying there is no such file or directory. Desktop has a Folder, a RTF file and an image file in it.

Comment: You could try `find /Users/student/Desktop -mindepth 1 -delete` instead, even though I'm a bit astonished that globbing (wildcard expansion) doesn't work.

Comment: operation not permitted for `find`, something **really** doesn't wan't me deleting these files

Comment: So we are back at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367020/allow-shell-script-to-access-protected-library-folders-launchd?rq=1

Comment: Tried this by creating an application through Platypus and through Script Editor, both ask for admin password on login (which the user won't know).